# Do all the valence electrons rise together in energy levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, particle-physics

I was working on some ideas and realized that all along I had been assuming that when an electron rises to another energy level that the other valence electrons (if any) did the same. I did a couple of quick searches and did not find anything but I will keep trying. Does anyone know how this process works? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite right to say "an electron rises to another energy level".  The *atom* rises to a new energy level.  All of the electrons in the system are involved in this.   It's often a good approximation to say that the electron moves from one level to another, but what actually happens is that the electron  makes a transition to a new orbital (set of quantum numbers).  That orbital has a shape and configuration that implies a higher energy for the electron.  But that same reconfiguration of the electron orbital affects all of the other electrons (primarily valence electrons) in the atom.  The other electrons "relax" into modified shape and configuration (without changing their quantum numbers).

Comment: Thanks that's what I assumed but like you mentioned everyone always says "the electron moves from one level to another"